# JNI Unsatisfied Link Error when calling the methods of one class but not the other

Tags: java, c++, dll, java-native-interface, native

I want to wrap a C++ library ([PCL](http://pointclouds.org/)) in Java code using JNI, but I am having inconsistent results. I have first created a `PointXYZ` class for testing and it looks like this:

```
package pcl;

public class PointXYZ extends NativeObject {

    PointXYZ() { }

    @Override
    public native void alloc();    // creates pointer + handle on the native side

    @Override
    public native void dispose();  // sets handle to 0 and deletes pointer

    public native float getX();

    // ...

}
```

I have generated the C header for this class using `javah`, compiled everything using CMake, tested it using its getters and setters and everything works perfectly.

```
    static {    
        System.setProperty("java.library.path", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/lib");
        System.loadLibrary("pcl_java_common");
    }

    @Test
    void attributeAccessTest() {
        PointXYZ p = new PointXYZ();

        p.alloc();

        p.setX(3);

        assertEquals(p.getX(), 3);

        p.dispose();

        // all is good
    }
```

Now I have done the exact same steps for a `PointXYZRGB` class which inherits from `PointXYZ` and when I try to test that it throws `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`. Here is the class:

```
package pcl; 

public class PointXYZRGB extends PointXYZ {

    public PointXYZRGB() { }

    @Override
    public native void alloc();

    @Override
    public native void dispose();

    public native short getR();

    // ...

}
```

I have checked the generated `.dll` using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and the `PointXYZRGB` methods are all present. Anyone knows what the problem could be?

**UPDATE:** Here are the `.dll` functions as requested in the comment:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the DLL functions too, so maybe someone can spot it, if there's something strange? And what is the error message of the `UnsatisfiedLinkError`?

Comment: The error message is: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: pcl.PointXYZRGB.alloc()V`, but I have tested with methods other than `alloc()` and the result is similar.

Comment: A guess: The `loadLibrary` is in the static initializer of the superclass. As I don't remember the exact steps when loading classes, I think it's possible that this initializer isn't executed yet, when the VM tries to resolve the native methods (and therefore the library isn't loaded at the time of the error).

Comment: I have found the solution, will post it soon: `System.setProperty("java.library.path", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/lib");` does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `System.setProperty("java.library.path", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/lib");` does not actually make Java look for `.dll` files in the given path. It essentially does nothing. Then why do the tests work for `PointXYZ`? This is was my mistake of having put an older `.dll` into the project root folder, so it was essentially looking for methods in that.